# How to add '' and , for multiple ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a `SELECT` query that has multiple id, and I have to manually add `'',''` (e.g `'12L','22C'`).

I have around 2000 id in an Excel sheet.

Is there any quicker way to add '','' to all the ID?

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN ('12L', '22C', 33j, 7k, 44J, 234C)
```

Comment: Usually better to find a *more appropriate* data type to pass the data to SQL Server in the first place, one *designed* for storing multiple values. If you're working programatically, you ought to be thinking table-valued parameters. If that's not possible, perhaps XML or JSON. Don't decide to use a string and pass that to the *relatively weak at string processing* T-SQL language.

Comment: WIthout context, a useful suggestion is not possible. If your "list" is in excel (which you did not tag), then it seems you should use Excel functionality to generate your string. Maybe use Excel to generate your query and execute it as well? And what do you do with this resultset? Does it go back into Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example for you. It will work in SQL Server 2012 onwards.

It is a three step process:

1. Convert input string into XML.
2. Convert XML into a relational resultset inside the CTE.
3. Join with a DB table.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Code VARCHAR(10), City VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Code, City) VALUES
('10T', 'Miami'),
('45L', 'Orlando'),
('50Z', 'Dallas'),
('70W', 'Houston');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100) = '22C,45L,50Z,105M'
    , @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

DECLARE @parameter XML = TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(@Str, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML);

;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS Code
   FROM @parameter.nodes('/root/r/text()') AS t(c)
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN 
   rs ON t.Code = rs.Code;
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
DECLARE @Ids VARCHAR(MAX) = '12L,22C,33j,7k,44J,234C'
```

```sql
--Your question's answer.
DECLARE @Splitted   VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((
    SELECT CONCAT(',''', value, '''')
    FROM string_split(@Ids, ',')
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @Splitted
--'12L','22C','33j','7k','44J','234C'
```

OR simplified

```sql
SELECT id, name from table where id in (SELECT value FROM string_split(@Ids, ','))
```

`string_split`: for more information [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`concat`: for more information [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives if you're ok doing the transformation outside of SQL.

---

As one of the comments on your question suggests, you could do this in Excel using this as a formula:

```
="'" & A1 & "',"
```

Replace the "A1" with whatever cell your first ID is in. After you enter the formula, click the cell it's in, and there will be a small square on the bottom right. Double click that and it will apply the formula to every cell in the column, automatically shifting the cell reference to match the current row. You can then copy the values from that column and erase the comma at the end.

---

You could also use an editor that supports regular expression like SSMS, Azure Data Studio, Notepad++, etc and do a Find+Replace:

1. Paste your IDs in
2. Hit the replace hotkey (Ctrl+H in all 3 of the ones I listed). There will be an option to enable Regular Expression (SSMS/ADS have a little `.*` icon, Notepad++ has a labeled radio button). Click it
3. Find this:

   ```
   (\w+)
   ```
4. Replace it with this

   ```
   '$1',
   ```
5. Copy and paste the formatted IDs into your query. Same as above, you'll have to erase the final comma

This will work as long as your IDs are alphanumeric with no spaces, punctuation, etc. If the formatting is more complex, the regex (the `(\w+)` you search for) will need to be more complex as well. Using this strategy, you could also get rid of the linebreaks by using the regex `(\w+)\r\n`.

Answer (score -1):

hei, you can use Function CONCATENATE in Excel before you copy those ID in sql.

Comment: I think this is too big shorthand. Can you edit your answer and provide the example code?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: if what the questioner meant was that he took the id in excel and then used it as a query on the "where", then he needed the ' ' sign for the string type, and the fastest way to add a sign like that was to use function concatenate in the id column in excel before being used in sql server .